# how to update entity based on the view filters criteria in crm 2011

Tags: xml, view, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, fetch

I'm trying to create a button that will fetch all records based on filters criteria in the view, until now I can create the button and run a page that does the updates of all records in an entity, but now i need to apply the filters criteria in the view, any idea? is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do this in Javascript? You can execute a saved view (named SavedQuery) in a plugin, try this:

```cs
using (ServiceContext svcContext = new ServiceContext(_serviceProxy))
{
    var viewFetchXml = (from q in svcContext.CreateQuery<SavedQuery>()
                        where q.Name == "Saved Query Name"
                        select q.FetchXml).FirstOrDefault();
    if (viewFetchXml != null)
    {
        FetchExpression query = new FetchExpression(viewFetchXml);
        EntityCollection results = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Pedro, i dont know if this is approach? I think this will have to be done through a custom workflow activity or plugin!

```
protected static EntityCollection GetInfo(string EntityName)
        {
            OrganizationService _orgService;
            String connectionString = CrmClasses.Operations.Configuration.GetServiceConfiguration();

            CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
            using (_orgService = new OrganizationService(connection))
            {
                QueryExpression request = new QueryExpression
                {
                    EntityName = EntityName,
                    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet { AllColumns = true },
                    Criteria =
                    {
                        Filters =
                                    {
     // -------------- insert here the filters criteria view?????????? --------
                      }
                    }                           
                };
                EntityCollection retrieved = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(request);
                return retrieved;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```